# My visual studio memory view does not show anything about the content of ints

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    const char* hello = "Hello loser!";

    int name1 = 23134;

    std::cout << hello << " " << name1 << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

It shows the memory of hello, but when I search name1, the memory is all ??

Why is this?  Is it a bug?  Have others experienced this?  My version is 17.1.2 community edition 2022

Comment: The `int` may be optimized out.

Comment: Debug build or Release build? Which line did you place a breakpoint on?

Comment: placed break on cin.get(), project configured to debug build according to project properties

Comment: It might be optimized out entirely, but another alternative is that it's stored in a register instead of in memory. Still, in Visual Studio debug builds `&name1` should point to the stack.

Comment: Why would int be optimized out if I told it to display int?  Telling it to display isn't useful enough?

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure about your meaning...

But if you mean you want to show the memory of name1, and search it by its address shown on console, you may use `&name1` to show its address.

And you also need to search the address while running but not after.